# Progress for DBCC SHRINKFILE

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a **database 21 Gb; 20 Gb of them are files (FileStream)** and I have delete all files from the table but when I make a backup the **backup file still 21 GB**.

To solve this problem I became the idee "free the unused space".

So I'm trying to **shrink** my database like the following:

```
USE Db;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE Db
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Db, 100);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE Db
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO

SELECT file_id, name
FROM sys.database_files;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (1, TRUNCATEONLY);
```

If I make a backup for the database after XX minutes then the backup file size is 1 Gb in this way,  I can see that the unused space have been successfully cleaned. In other words the above Sql code working properly(*Database after XX minutes is schrunk*).

---

**The problem** I need to wait until this query(Shrinking operation) is finished so I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT percent_complete, start_time, status, command, estimated_completion_time, cpu_time, total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
```

I can not find any information about the SHRINKFILE command in results of the above query.

[image]

---

***Did I do something wrong? why I can not see the progress of DB shrinking operation?***

***And my main quesiton is: How can I wait until the SHRINKFILE is finished?***
For example can I send from my C# code query and in the result of this query I shall get the information that the SHRINKFILE operation is finsihed or not?

Comment: You do realize that this both fragments your database and breaks the log chain, right?  This is not something that you should *ever* automate because 1) you should *never* automate shrinking a database, and 2) Your database recovery capability is in jeopardy until you finish the next full backup.  You should only ever do this manually, on an exception basis, and personally watch over it until it is done.  Otherwise you are inviting a host of problems, some of them disastrous.

Comment: I agree with in all; That why I need to block everything changing the database while shrinking for example add remove entries backup, etc. The problem this is our customer requirements they need the unused space on the harddisk I must do it.

Comment: For me is also enough just to know when this process is finished and not a progress bar all I need to know When ShrinkFile operation is finished in SQL statement for example the process SPID not available anymore and I can pool that from C#

Comment: I'm open for any new idea also for reclaim or reduce the database size.

Comment: If u can change the recovery mode of your DB from full to simple without backups, why do you need the full mode in this case? In case of simple recovery mode the space used by the database can be reduced...

Comment: Thanks @Sandr for the good hint; if I leave the Database mode in Simple Revovery mode will this cause any problem with DB backup or restore process! or login privilege and permissions?

Comment: @Sandr with Simple Recovery mode same problem after deleting the stream files I must call DBCC ShrinkFile and it took undefined time until is finished

Comment: @BassamAlugili why the bounty? MikeFal is certainly credible as his community involvement would certainly support.

Comment: @swasheck thanks for your comments; I have hoping to find a better soultion for this problem! because I'm not doing something strange(uncommon); I think ShrinkDB problem should be solved from a lot of another developers; I'm really convinced there must another simple soultion!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with measuring progress of `DBCC SHRINKFILE` is that there's not consistent way for the engine to know how much work needs to be done to shrink a file.  To understand this is to know how `DBCC SHRINKFILE` works.  Basically, the process is:

- You declare you want to shrink a file to a certain point (say 5 GB,
  down from 10 GB).
- The engine will start moving pages from the end of the file to the next open spot near the beginning of the file.

[image: Shrink File Movement]

- The engine keeps going until A) it moves enough pages under your declared point that it can reduce the file size or B) that all the empty space is on the back end of the file.

So why does this mean that SQL Server doesn't know how much work needs to be done?  Because it doesn't know how fragmented your empty space is in the file.  If things are fairly well compacted and near the front of the file, the shrink file will go quickly.  If not, it can take a long while.  The good news is that once pages are moved within the file, they're moved.  Cancelling a shrink file does not undo/rollback this work, so if you have a shrink file running for a while, then kill it before it completes, all that page movement stays intact.  Meaning you can then restart the shrink file at *almost* the point you left off (barring any new page creation within the file).

Comment: thanks for answer; this is true what you say but how can I can detect that the shrink operation are running!? I can pool it until it finished.

Comment: You can see it under sp_who2 where command is DbccSpaceReclaim or using [sp_whoisactive](http://sqlblog.com/files/default.aspx).

Comment: I cannot see DbCCSpaceReclaim but I can see somthing new called AWAITINGCOMMAND this came new direct after shrink I will mark the SPID  and I will check it if this the shrink process I will wait until this spid will finished Thanks a lot i will mark the answer when I finish.

Comment: I will loop during all SPID in the sp_who2 and With dbcc inputbuffer I can see in the eventInfo ShrinkFile and I can see the process in progress and sleeping or running I will poll it from C# or to make sure the job is finished or not or I will use SqlDependency  to fire a event when it finished in a stored procdure.

Comment: I Will post my Stroed procedure(Detect ShrinkFile is running) and you can update in the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the problem in a different way but this solution does not need any polling or waiting for threads and it isvery practice.

This approach will not reorganize the table indices but only remove the streaming files from the harddisk and reclaim the free space to OS.

Importent to know the below code will work on the same thread; So this will not notfiy you about the Shrink process progress but only run it on the application thread.

```
    var db = EFDbContext;
    try 
    {
        db.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"USE [master]

                                   ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
                                   SET RECOVERY SIMPLE");

        db.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"USE [master]

                                   EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection 'DatabaseName'");

        db.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"USE [master]

                                   EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection 'DatabaseName'");
      }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new DatabaseException(e.Message, e);
    }
    finally
    {
             db.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"USE [master]
                                    ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
                                    SET RECOVERY FULL");
    }
```

Comment: what does this script do?